# Null object error when retrieving TFS project collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

***Question background:***

I'm currently trying to retrieve the project information in team foundation server I have that contains a simple HelloWorld project. I want to be able to get the name of all the .cs/proj files etc.

I have implemented one solution that uses the depreciated TeamFoundationSeverFactory object.

This only supplies me with the project name - in this case 'TfsTestxxxxxxxxx' and not the folders contained within it i.e HelloWorld, as shown:

[image]

***Where the code is currently at:***

I have found the following solution that seems towhat I am after. This should produce the file details within the projects:

```
        string tfsServer = @"https://tfstestxxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection";

        TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServer));

        ProjectCollection projCollect = (ProjectCollection)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(ProjectCollection));

        VersionControlServer vcs = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        // This approach lets you get the list of files for each team project individually.

        foreach (TeamProject tp in projCollect)
        {
            string path = string.Format("$/{0}", tp.Name);
            var filesAndFolders = vcs.GetItems(path, RecursionType.Full);
        }
```

***The error:***

On the following line of code, I should be receiving the project collection(s) from the explorer but this is always being set to null. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?:

```
       //*****ERROR: 'projCollect' is always set to 'null'.
       ProjectCollection projCollect = (ProjectCollection)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(ProjectCollection))
```

***Update:***

***The given error message:***

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

Additional information: TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://tfsdaveharris.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection.

Team Foundation Server Url: https://tfsdaveharris.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection.

Possible reasons for failure include:

- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: Is your URI definitely correct?

Comment: @pm_2 It has been used in that format when implementing another other TFS SDK objects with no issue so I believe it is yes.

Comment: @pm_2 I have updated the question with the error message given.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to Visual Studio Online you need to provide your credentials. Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx) that describes setting up alternate credentials along with a code sample.